# When was "untactful" first used?

Tags: etymology, terminology, history

I came across "**untactful**" in a story and wondered when it was first used and how it came to be commonly used in speech. I've always used "tactless".

---

I checked a lot of dictionaries with no results.
I searched for "origins of untactful" and "etymology of untactful" with no results.

I had no trouble finding the information about "tactless". It was first recorded in 1840–50 but had no luck with "untactful".

Google Stats - infers that "untactful" is new:

- "untactful" = About 547,000 results
- "tactless" = About 1,480,000 results

Thanks!

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=untactful&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuntactful%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/218699?redirectedFrom=untactful#eid) lists early usage of **untactful** as 1860:

> 1860   E. Eden Semi-attached Couple I. xx. 181   When her vanity was
>   in a state of mortification, she became unusually **untactful**.

But its usage is in the bottom 10% of word usage!